# Creating an Outlook profile On a Citrix Application Session

Tags: citrix, outlook-2003

We have an application that runs from a Citrix session that can email information out, outlook 2003 is installed on the Citrix server.

As the user lauches the app from the program neigborhood i need to be able to create an outlook profile on that session.

I have my prf file and that does work, i have tried using outlook to import the file using outlook.exe /importprf \server1\share\outlook.prf but this also opens outlook, which i do not want to do.

I need to import the prf file silently as part of the login script, so it is ready for the user to email from the other application

Cheers
Luke

Comment: I am in similar situation. Can I have the script please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get this working now via a Kix32 script, if anyone is interested ill post it up

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Citrix is immaterial here so you can use any standard resolutions.

I think you need to read this page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-2003-resource-kit/customizing-outlook-profiles-by-using-prf-files-HA001140258.aspx

Specifically the last section titled "Applying Outlook user profiles by using a PRF file". You should be able to put the reference to the PRF file in the registry:

> **Configure the registry to trigger Outlook to import the PRF file when Outlook starts up.**
>
> You can use the Add/Remove Registry Entries page in Custom
>   Installation Wizard or the Custom Maintenance Wizard to deploy these
>   registry key options to your users. You can also use the wizards to
>   distribute the PRF file to users by using the Add/Remove Files page.
>
> Delete the following registry key values:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Setup\First-Run
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Setup\FirstRun
> ```
>
> In the
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Setup`
>   subkey, set the value of ImportPRF to a string value that specifies
>   the name and path of the PRF file. For example, set ImportPRF to
>   \server1\share\outlook.prf.

Comment: I have tried this, it does create the profile but only when outlook runs. Outlook is not running on the Citrix side its installed locally so it never runs to create the profile. If i could maybe get outlook to start then quit it might be a start, but its not ideal

Comment: If Outlook isn't running on Citrix then why does it matter if the profile is there?

Comment: The application we use needs a mail profile for the current user so it can send emails out

Comment: Apologies for being dense, I've just never seen this type of implementation before. So, it sends e-mails, but DOESN'T open Outlook to do it? But it uses the Outlook mail profile to do it? Intriguing, if so and I do see your issue.

Do the users use Outlook in their normal roles off Citrix?

Comment: It is kind of odd, it seems to check there is a profile before launching outlook, if it cant find a profile it wont go any further. I've managed to get it working now with a kix script